# Getting Plain Text(non Form-urlencoded) data from Request using Flask

Tags: java, python, flask, jax-rs

I am new to Flask. I am trying to figure out how to grab a request body as a String rather then a key:value param pair.

In java using jax-rs this is easy using the following:

```
@POST
@Path("/returnText")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing but using python + flask instead.
I have the following code but everytime I run it, it says I am missing a parameter:

```
@app.route("/REST/message",methods=['POST'])
def message(name):
return "Hello " + name;
```

Should I be using the flask.request attribute instead? and if so which attribute should I be using to print plain text from the request body?

Comment: Yes, the function shouldn’t have any argument if there is no argument in the route. You should use request.form.get(name) inside the function.

Comment: Thing is I am trying to get String data not a key:value pair. For example with curl: curl -X POST -d "name" http://localhost:9007/REST/message

Answer (score 1):

Try adding headers

```py
@app.route("/REST/message",methods=['POST'])
def message():
    headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain","Accept":"text/plain"}
    return make_response('Hello ' + request.data.decode(),
                         200,
                         headers=headers)
```

Comment: I have tried this,however I am still left with it saying that I am missing a parameter in message(). The exact error is :"TypeError: message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'  "

Comment: Are you sending name as a parameter in request?

Comment: No and neither was I using it in the jax-rs example. What I am trying to do is the following: curl -X POST -d "name" http://localhost:9007/REST/message. So a plain-text String not a key:value pair.

Comment: Tried this as well awhile back. Kept getting: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: Modified answer as @Tim said.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same question in **Python3 + Flask** combination. My task was:

1. Send plain text in http POST request to Flask-server (on pythonanywhere.com) using cmd Windows 10
2. Save this raw text on the server and print text on another page

**What I did?**

1. To check how my code works I used: [Postman in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). Good examples were [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask)
2. To send text from my txt-file to server (in win10) I used ***.bat** file with text:

- `curl --request POST --url http://<myservername>.pythonanywhere.com/message --header "content-type: text/plain" -d @<myfilename>.txt`

3. And this code in my Flask-app:

```
    import os
    import datetime

    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route("/message",methods=['POST'])
    def message():
        with open(os.path.join(app.root_path,"myfile.txt"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(request.get_data().decode())
        return "Data updated %s" % datetime.datetime.now()
    
    @app.route('/print-file')
    def print_file():
        with open(os.path.join(app.root_path,"myfile.txt"), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            d = f.read()
        return d
```

Sorry, I don't know how it works in java. GLHF!